# Сохранятся ли личные файлы в папке home при обновлении Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Не произойдёт ли удаления личных файлов в папке home при обновлении Ubuntu, если папка etc(где, как я понял сама ОС) и папка home(где находятся личные файлы: фото, видео и т.д.) находятся в одном разделе? А именно в корневом разделе "/".
Простите, что спрашиваю, мб глупость, просто я новичок в линуксах.

Comment: Обновление Ubuntu занимается именно обновлением, а не удалением чего-либо. Если вы, конечно, не собрались делать полную переустановку

Comment: Согласен с @andreymal, но это не значит, что бэкапы делать не надо. Загугли про "бэкапы 3-2-1".

Comment: `если папка etc(где, как я понял сама ОС)` - нет, это не сама ОС, это тока её часть где хранятся системные конфиги. Что касается обновления, то нет, это никак не повлияет на пользовательскую папку `home`, единственная проблем с таким размещением(на одном разделе с корнем) это если что-то пойдёт не так при обновлении и вам по итогу покажется что проще переустановить систему чем исправить, то да, переустановка потрет данные на всём разделе вместе с хомяком, поэтому нужно будет предварительно загрузиться с liveusb и перекинуть данные в другое место, а после переустановки вернуть

Comment: Понял. Буду изучать тематические форумы по линукс. Спасибо за ответы